# vimdiff: Move cursor into a block of deleted lines

Tags: vim, vimdiff

When I open two files using vimdiff side by side I cannot put the cursor into a block of deleted lines. vimdiff instead jumps over them. How can I configure vimdiff such that diffs are still side by side with the matching lines next to each other but I can move the cursor into the block of deleted lines?

I tried to use vimdiff options like iwhite with the idea to treat deleted lines the same as empty lines in the output but this did not work.

Comment: There is no line to move to, in that block. But you can move the cursor to the other window with `<C-w>w`, where you can move the cursor into the non-deleted lines.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the shortcut! I knew I could switch windows but doing that manually for each deleted block is rather cumbersome. Is there maybe a plugin which automatically switches to other other window once you encounter such a block? I consider the default behaviour of jumping over the block unpleasant as I want to check what was deleted line by line.